# 401 authentication error from gcloud ruby on rails app

Tags: api, ruby-on-rails-4, basic-authentication, gcloud

I setup ruby on rails backend project on gcloud and now when i am trying to fetch data to a WordPress site using `wp_remote_get()` method from my `json` API. the

```
https://gcloud-assigend-domain.com/api/v1/auth/signin
```

> gcloud is returning me 401 authentication,

although the same thing is working fine at my localhost.

Via wp page i am sending user email and password to API so i can get token-access, client-id, uid and expiry to process.

If anyone aware of this please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to set the header to `'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',`

so i just add the header to `wp_remote_post()` method and fixed the issue.

```
'headers' => array(
    'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
),
```